# describe-variable show characters instead of numbers

Tags: keymap, variables

Is there a way to have `describe-variable` show characters instead of numbers where it makes sense?

Here's for example output of `describe-variable word-separating-categories`:

> word-separating-categories is a variable defined in `C source code'.
>   Its value is ((72 . 75))
>
> Documentation: List of pair (cons) of categories to determine word
>   boundary. See the documentation of the variable
>   `word-combining-categories'.

It would help if instead ((72 . 75)) it would show something meaningful.

Comment: You could probably pipe the value of the variable through `char-to-string`.

Answer (score 2):

In Emacs a character ***is*** an integer.  There is no way for `describe-variable` to know that the value of this variable is a list that contains conses with car and cdr that you want to see rendered as characters.

But you can use something like this:

```el
(mapcar (lambda (cs)
          (cons (format "%c" (car cs)) (format "%c" (cdr cs))))
        word-separating-categories)
```

Comment: But it is certainly  technically possible to provide a way for `describe-variable` to know such things. For example, by adding a suitable property to the symbol containing relevant information. I think a case could be made that this would be a useful enhancement to emacs.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I initially was going to suggest that the OP use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to request an enhancement of `describe-variable`. But I don't think it is very feasible. Certainly the usual approach of using "character" before the name in the docstring would not work, as the characters are within a larger structure. And what property value would you provide, for your suggestion? The value is not a character; it is a list of conses of characters. You would need an elaborate type-defining mechanism similar to what Customize `:type` offers, and that is certainly overengineering here.

Comment: One possibility for the property could be a function to compute a string describing the value. For robustness, the function could return nil or throw an error in case of unexpected data, leaving `describe-variable` to use the standard display as a fallback. The cost of adding this functionality to `describe-variable` would be negligible – the cost of adding such functions to relevant variables, less trivial. But one doesn't have to do them all from day one.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Go for it, if you think it is worthwhile - `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Include a patch...

Comment: Hmm. Looking at the source code, I realize that the function called should probably be expected to prettyprint the result if it is large. That complicates things quite considerably.

Answer (score 0):

`print1-to-string` is used during making display string of the variable's value, so maybe you can try to hijack that, use, e.g.

```el
(defun display-in-char-p (var val)
  (or (eq 'word-separating-categories var)
      (numberp val)
      (and (listp val) (ignore-errors (seq-every-p #'numberp val)))))

(defun describe-variable-hack (orig-fun &rest args)
  (when (display-in-char-p (car args) (symbol-value (car args)))
    (advice-add 'prin1-to-string :filter-return
                (defun prin1-to-string-hack (rtv)
                  (replace-regexp-in-string
                   "[0-9]+"
                   (lambda (match) (string (string-to-number match)))
                   rtv))))
  (unwind-protect (apply orig-fun args)
    (advice-remove 'prin1-to-string #'prin1-to-string-hack)))

(advice-add 'describe-variable :around #'describe-variable-hack)
```